# How would I add a "foo().variable" to my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm pretty new to Python, and I've been curious to figure out how to do something like this:

```py
requests.get('https://website.com/').text
```

Now, what if I wanted to create a function and add the '.text' to the end of my function I've created?

Comment: What do you mean with add '.text' to the end of the function?

Comment: First: What do you want your `.text` property to return? Second, why not create an object that returns said property? What is your use case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
requests.get('https://website.com/')
```

returns an object of type Response. This type contains a field named `text`, which you access by doing `.text` as you're doing. Similarly, this is equivalent to

```
class Response:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.text = "Some text"

def get(url):
    return Response(url)

# Evaluates to Some text
get('https://website.com/').text
```